# How to define/process NiFi FlowFile content without a schema?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have been experimenting with Nifi (via Hortonworks HDF) and can't grasp something that seems basic. I start with a file..I want to filter records based on a value (e.g., field number 2 contains "xyz")...then write only the matching records to HDFS.

I have a non-filtered flow working but can't find any docs or examples showing how to apply a schema (or in any way understand the "content") of the file.

What am I missing?

(I have seen references to FlowFiles being "schema-less" - not sure how that is useful).

For example, a file like this:

```
[app1][field1][field2]
[app2][field1][field2]
[app2][field1][field2][field3]
[app3][field1]
```

I want to filter to select records containing "[app2]" and create an HDFS file that looks like this:

```
field1,field2
field1,field2,field3
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about your input file such as the format of the data?  For example, let's say it is text data in a line oriented format.  You can use RouteText to search for patterns per line and route results to a given output.  You can then combine/merge those results into larger aggregates appropriate to your HDFS block size and write them to HDFS.

Comment: Do you have a canonical concept of a "record" or is this just a single atomic unit of data that originates from an arbitrary source? NiFi ships with processors for parsing `JSON`, `CSV`, `XML`, and many other formats by default. It also supports operations like `XPath`, `JOLT`, etc. And of course, if you can't find a pre-built processor to perform the transformation you need, the `ExecuteScript` processor allows for on-the-fly actions with dynamic code in Groovy, Python, Scala, JS, or Lua.   If you can offer more details, I'm sure someone will offer a successful solution.